# Is there a way to disable member function in a template class in c++ for visual studio 2010 ( no default function template params )

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, enable-if

For example

```
#include "boost/type_traits.hpp"
template <bool enable>
struct Foo {

    template <bool e = enable>
    typename boost::enable_if_c<e,void>::type  DoStuff(){}

};

int main(){
    // Compiles
    Foo<true>().DoStuff();
    // Fails
    Foo<false>().DoStuff();
}
```

will work in modern compilers but not with visual studio 2010 which does not allow default template params for functions / methods. Is there another way to formulate the same task that will work with VS2010?

Comment: What about uncompilable template specialization for false?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean sorry.

Comment: tag dispatching/full specialization/or [CRTP](https://wandbox.org/permlink/62FcHRPEkc6onwUq)

Comment: You can create specialization of Foo<false> with some kind of static_assert inside void DoStuff(){}.
Or just do as @NathanOliver says)

Comment: Have you considered just upgrading your (almost) decade old compiler and using modern C++?

Comment: @jesper legacy code with legacy support contracts to paying customers. a.k.a the real world.

Answer (score 4):

You could specialize the entire class like

```
template <bool enable>
struct Foo {};

template <>
struct Foo<true> {
    void DoStuff(){}
};

template <>
struct Foo<false> {

};
```

And then

```
int main(){
    // Compiles
    Foo<true>().DoStuff();
    // Fails
    Foo<false>().DoStuff();
}
```

Comment: Specialising the entire class is difficult if I only have one method I want to disable and 50 standard ones. But a useful answer anyway.

Comment: @bradgonesurfing In that case you could leverage inheritance.  Put all of the common functions in a base and specialize for the differences.  This will save a lot of code replication (it's the DRY way).

Answer (score 2):

You could discard DoStuff via SFINAE:

```
template<bool enable>
struct Foo {
private:
    static void SFINAE_Helper(std::true_type);
    typedef std::integral_constant<bool, enable> tag;
public:
    decltype(SFINAE_Helper(tag())) DoStuff() { }
};
```

Besides the fact that this code is quite unreadable it has the advantage, that you do not need to make extra specializations but can have all your code in one class template.

**EDIT**

An alternative could look like that:

```
template<bool enable>
struct Foo {
private:
    typedef std::enable_if<enable> enable_tag;
public:
    typename enable_tag::type DoStuff() {}
};
```